Worst peg solitaire game
I wonder if there is an algorithm for the worst game to keep as many pegs as possible.
I tried to search for "peg solitaire worst score/ max leave" etc, but it’s not quite that.
The question applies to both classic and generalized versions of the game.
For example, which is presented in my favourite Simon Tatham collection.
Starting with this configuration:

I managed to save the maximum number of pegs.
Firstly it was 6:

And due to the motivation of @Daniel Mathias now it's 8:

 

Is there any idea of an algorithm to prove/find the needed steps?

Here is the same question (and answer) about triangle solitaire. I don't think there is a clever algorithm for this, other than straightforward breadth first search.

As for your example, the maximum is at least 8. For others wanting to try, the game ID is 5x5:OOPPOOOPPPPPHPOPOPPOPPPPO

@JaapScherphuis, yes thank you!  So we see that the boundaries are important.
And another question appears: for given board place (starting from empty) as many pegs as possible without possible move
